# Need help with Mobile CSS instead of jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, mobile

There is no way for me to control the pages of our mobile site, however I can modify the CSS.  My goals is to hide an element so it doesn't appear on our mobile site. If there is a way to tell it to use the closest `<tr>` I would be fine.  **If I could use jQuery I would do this but I cannot**:

`$('.ex').closest('tr').attr('style', 'display:none')`

```
<table>
....
<tr>
  <td colspan="2">
    <font class="colors_productname">
      <span class="mapprice"></span>
    </font>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr> **/* I WANT TO DISPLAY:NONE HERE /***
  <td colspan="2">
      <span class="ex">Exclusive Price</span>
      <font color="red">&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><br>
      <select>
        <option value="1636">[Subtract -$282.34]</option>
      </select>
  </td>
</tr>
...
</table>
```

I believe I am close but it doesnt hide the select yet:

```
option[value="1636"] {display:none}

span.ex + font + select{display:none}
```

Comment: You could try `tr:nth-child(2)`, but it's not universally supported -- http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/understandingnthchildexpressions

Comment: Thank you this is a start.  I need to find a way to use its class as this is only on some pages and I wouldn't want to hide the row on ALL pages, only those with `class="ex"`

Comment: If you can't use any javascript then you are limited to what you can do with css and unfortunately it might not work in all browsers.

Comment: `tr:contains()` might help you, but it only accepts text strings (not class names) in the parentheses. Would `tr:contains("Exclusive Price")` do the trick?  http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#content-selectors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out.  Since this is using mobile css it may not work on all older phones:

```
.ex {display: none}
span.ex + font + br + select{display:none}
```